# Swift Package Manager failed with: invalid archive returned from XY which is required by binary target

Tags: xcode, bitbucket, swift-package-manager, matlab-spm

When adding the usercentrics package in swift package manager i get the following error:

`invalid archive returned from 'https://bitbucket.org/usercentricscode/usercentrics-spm-sdk/downloads/Usercentrics-2.8.1.xcframework.zip' which is required by binary target 'Usercentrics'`

[image]

When i download the framework in browser it returns a valid framework for the different platforms.

[image: Framework folders]

however when i try to do `git clone` (not sure if this is the right way to test it) it clones a folder with only a package.swift

[image]

I tried to remove any bitbucket ssh keys or certificates i might have. i cleaned the project, deleted derived data and reset the package cache. unfortunately without success. Searching for this error message did also not yield any results. usercentrics (in case this is specific to their repo) could also, as of now, not provide a solution to this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even I am seeing same error, did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This error seems non-existant on the internet. Good to know i'm not alone :/

Comment: Do you know if there are any ways of seeing some logs or contents of what this "invalid archive" looks like? I have the same issue and find it difficult to debug.

Comment: Found a solution for me in this github thread: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/6635

Turned out it was some issue with macOS keychain and bitbucket.

Comment: WTF. thank you ❤️ I never expected that i have to delete all credentials of bitbucket in order to resolve this. I have already deleted certificates and all, but no passwords. Month-long struggle is finally over . Can you please add this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by @steffen-funke from the comments:

> Found a solution for me in this github thread: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/6635
>
> Turned out it was some issue with macOS keychain and bitbucket.

So looking for bitbucket credentials in keychain and deleting them (it's probably one that has been autocreated and is not used anyway) solved the issue. Hooray

Comment: Haha... was sent back to this page because I again had this issue and searched about it. Totally forgot about my comment above. Thanks for making a proper answer out of my comment, let me upvote it!  (I am a bit envious about the green checkmark, tho )

Comment: No problem, you can answer it your own and  i will delete mine :) I just wanted to resolve the question and wasn't sure if you were coming back 

Comment: No worries, it's all fine 

Answer (score -1):

I've the same issue and I resolved by integrating the dependencies with Cocoapods:
https://docs.usercentrics.com/cmp_in_app_sdk/latest/getting_started/install/

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it. great if it works for you, but we're not going back to cocoapods, just because one 3rd Party framework is misbehaving :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.